# Sqlite en múltiples dispositivos

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, xamarin

Buen dia

Mi duda es un poco tonta pero necesito el concepto, estoy desarrollando una app en Xamarin para iOS y Android el problema parece ser que muchas trabas tiene en recibir consultas de los webservices php con su base de datos MySql, y estoy pensando en rediseñar con Sqlite.

Mi duda es al Sqlite no necesitar un servidor, ya que entiendo que ocupa las tablas y datos en el dispositivo local, como es que el resto de usuarios pueden ver cambios en su app es decir si el usuario A hace un Insert en una tabla como ve el usuario B esa nueva inserción?

Gracias

Comment: Cuales son las supuestas trabas que tendria mysql? y has mirado firebase para lo que queres hacer? sqlite es local a cada dispositivo, igual necesitarias un replicador para los datos...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto se logra a través del proceso de replicación asi como en Sqlite en MySQL y en otros motores de bases de datos las bases de datos pueden replicar su información desde Servidor A -> Servidor B, replicación Unidireccional o Maestro-Esclavo también hay replicaciones Bidireccionales A <-> B, investiga replicación de Bases de datos para aclarar tu duda.
saludos.

Comment: Esto no responde a la pregunta. Por favor, revisa [answer] . Cuando tengas más reputación podrás comentar en las preguntas.

Comment: Y en que parte de mi respuesta según tú, mi respuesta no responde a la pregunta?.

Comment: Gracias @KenThompson era mas que nada una duda de concepto y con esto puedo estudiarlo mejor, perdon si la pregunta era algo tonta

Comment: No es para nada tonta, lo mejor es aclarar los conceptos para no hacer trabajo en vano, saludos